# Find First Value not Equal to Either of Two Values

Tags: microsoft-excel

With data in column **A** like:

[image]

and I want to find the first cell in the column that is **not** *misery*, I can use the *Array Formula*:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,A1:A11<>"misery",0)
```

which correctly returns ***3***.  Now I want the first cell in the column that is neither *misery* nor *sadness*.  The formula should return ***9***.  The following array formulas do not work:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,(A1:A11<>"misery")*(A1:A11<>"sadness"),0)
=MATCH(TRUE,AND((A1:A11<>"misery"),(A1:A11<>"sadness")),0)
```

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=MATCH(1,(A1:A11<>"misery")*(A1:A11 <> "sadness"),0)
```

Array formulas do not like the AND.  Also the return of multiplying two booleans is `1` when both are TRUE, not TRUE.

Comment: Thanks Scott................. *I forgot the second condition.*